# Quadrupoles in an accelerator

Tags: magnetic-fields, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

The quadrupole magnets in a particle accelerator are just to center de beam or do they have any other application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quadrupole magnets in a beam are not used to center the beam, but to focus it.

Even if the beam is centered, each particle in the beam has a slightly different transverse momentum and position relative to the beam center. A pair of quadrupoles (called a FODO cell) is used to reduce this deviation. A pair is required because a quadrupole that focuses along one axis defocuses along the other access, and so a pair is required to give a net focusing effect.